# Programming HTTP Server in Linux for custom POST-GET requests (which language-framework)

Tags: python, http, sdk

I need to program a custom simple HTTP server for ZKSoftware fingerprint sensors, which use a kind of push sdk:

[Poor documented requests schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NADG7.png)

The sensors send GET requests which can listen by a HTTP custom server which has to answer with commands coded in GET response. This will generate more HTTP requests from the sensors, this time with information to store and so. That procedures are very poor documented by ZkSoftware but after a few hours capturing and analyzing traffic, I am able to program my own server for reduced features I need.

The problem is that the server must be coded in Linux environment I don't know which language/framework use. I need to use one that:

-Allow me to listen HTTP requests and let me answer with custom HTTP responses
-Allow me to store information received in some simple database such us mysql

I have searched in stackoverflow but often the framework or language seems to be too simple, and can't manage a database (INSERT/UPDATE/SELECT), or it is not possible to build good custom reponses.

I have read about Python as a good language to do it but I don't know how to start with it in Linux in order to make this.

Thank you all for any clue or starting point.

Answer (score 0):

if you want Python server frameworks : Flask, Django, CherryPy.
databases with python integration: SQLite, MySQL .

regarding "where to start?" - google Python and see in the docs how to install it on linux (although it comes built-in in any major Linux distro).